# Json array parsing with python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have python 2.7.6 installed and I need to parse the following json. I am bound to work with this version of python using no other external libraries.

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "author": {
        "value": "plugin-demo Administrator",
        "origin": "http://localhost:8080/webservice/person/18"
      },
      "creator": {
        "value": "plugin-demo Administrator",
        "origin": "http://localhost:8080/webservice/person/18"
      },
      "creationDate": "2015-11-04T15:14:18.000+0600",
      "lastModifiedDate": "2015-11-04T15:14:18.000+0600",
      "model": "http://localhost:8080/plugin-editorial/model/281/football",
      "payload": [
        {
          "name": "basic",
          "value": "Real Madrid are through"
        }
      ],
      "publishDate": "2015-11-04T15:14:18.000+0600"
    },
    {
      "author": {
        "value": "plugin-demo Administrator",
        "origin": "http://localhost:8080/webservice/person/18"
      },
      "creator": {
        "value": "plugin-demo Administrator",
        "origin": "http://localhost:8080/webservice/person/18"
      },
      "creationDate": "2015-11-04T15:14:18.000+0600",
      "lastModifiedDate": "2015-11-04T15:14:18.000+0600",
      "model": "http://localhost:8080/plugin-editorial/model/281/football",
      "payload": [
        {
          "name": "basic",
          "value": "Real Madrid are through"
        }
      ],
      "publishDate": "2015-11-04T15:14:18.000+0600"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to access each json object in the json array. (e.g. entries[0], entries[1] etc...)
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module. It's been available since Python 2.6.

```
import json

jsonString= json.loads(string)
entries = jsonString['entries']

print entries[0]
print entries[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

dictData = json.loads(strJsonString)
```